# Read Value and Assign to While Loop

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, while-loop, radio-button

Currently I'm working on a program in `WPF`, that on display screen user can select 2 options:

1. All (`RadiobtnAll`)
2. Number (`RadiobtnText`)+(`TextboxNumber`)

These two value should assign to the 'X' variable.

Then I'm going to have a `while` loop that will run the base of these two conditions:

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= x ; i++)
  {
     //Do Stuff
  }
```

I'm not quiet sure how I should do these as I'm totally new to `WPF`.

Comment: are you trying to determine what radio button was selected..? not sure I fully understand your question..

Comment: Yes Both are radio button but for Number i have text box to get the value,

Comment: how many radiobuttons are there you can only select a single option with radio button.. perhaps you need to use a GroupTextBox you're not making any sense here.. also why do you have to do your code in a while loop please explain your requirements better Alexandera

Comment: i have two radio button, either one have a different value ( if i select all my while loop will run until the other inner condition become false and then stop and exit the loop ) and ( if i select the Number radiobutton and i assign value in the box the while loop will run until the number is equal to zero)

Comment: and what seems to be the problem because you still haven't explained why you need a while loop..I think that you need to show more code because what you are doing still make Zero Sense..

Comment: i understand i have to change my while loop to for Loop in order to Run it base on 'X' value but how to get radiobutton values?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: you can do something like this Alexandera `string value=Radiobtn.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();` please explain once again why you need a for loop as well if you are trying to get the value of the selected `Radiobtn`

Comment: how can i get the value of textbox and assign it to int x?( int x=textbox.Getvalue)

Comment: That won't work if the end-user puts a `string` in the textbox, Alexandera.  If `x` **must** be an `int`, use `int.TryParse(textbox, out x)`.

Comment: @Brian , you have a good point but how i can do these? im new in WPF

Comment: `WPF` has a pretty steep learning curve.  Just to make sure that I am understanding, you have a `radiobutton` and a `textbox` on the form?  The user can select one or the other, or both, right?  In any of those 3 cases, you need to assign an `int` value to `x` (or some other variable)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're writing this to have a while loop constantly running to check if x has been assigned. This isn't how you would do it in WPF, but how you'd do it in a video game.

What you want to look into is events, here is a nice [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465336.aspx) by Microsoft that should be able to help you.

edit: The Thread code;

```
private int _x = 0;
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var waitThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= _x; i++)
        {
            //Do Logic
        }
    });
    waitThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: the fact is i have to do it in these way only, thanks for your link but not helpful as i have to return a value to main function

Comment: Ah, then are you targeting .net 4.5?

Comment: I would say use a Thread, and have the checking x code inside that. I'll edit my main post with the code.